# Using Applescript to create a Smart Mailbox?

Tags: email, macos, applescript

I am trying to automate the creation of a smart mailbox in Apple Mail using criteria based on the currently selected message (e.g. create a folder to display all messages from the person who sent the current message).  Clearly, I can go in and create a smart mailbox by hand, but because I do this regularly I am hoping to automate it.

I could not find any reference to Smart Mailboxes in the Dictionary for Mail.  I did an internet search and could not find any sample code for manipulating Smart Mailboxes in Applescript, only a reference in a discussion from 2006 that says (bottom of the thread) that it can't be done: http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-51935.html

I also found a script to bring up the create smart mailbox dialog, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Anyone know if there's a way to create/edit a smart mailbox in AppleScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use GUI scripting.  I do most of my scripting using Python + appscript but here's a quick Applescript fragment to create a Smart Mailbox.  I should note that not having formal Applescript support for handling smart mailbox is ludicrous.

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
end tell
```

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Mailbox"
                tell menu "Mailbox"
                    click menu item "New Smart Mailbox…"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell

`delay 1
    keystroke "t" using shift down
    keystroke "e"
    keystroke "s"
    keystroke "t"
    keystroke tab
    keystroke "m"
    keystroke "o"
    keystroke "r"
    keystroke "e"
end tell`

end tell